# Any tutorial on libclang?

Tags: llvm, libclang

I've been looking for some easy to understand guide into libclang. I've seen some threads either here or other forums but the only recommended sources of information were libclang source/doxygen doc, clang complete plugin for vim or [Thinking Beyond the Compiler](http://devimages.apple.com/llvm/videos/Libclang.mov) presentation. However, none of them provide information on practical usage. I'm interested in implementing code completion/syntax highlighting (maybe some basic refactoring/parsing).

So my question is, is there any easy to understand tutorial except of those mentioned above ? Maybe some of advanced libclang users can write one :)

Note : I'm not interested in writing plugins for clang.

Comment: I've written a tutorial about [implementing a code generator with libclang](http://szelei.me/code-generator/). It covers the basic usage of the library.

Answer (score 20):

I've written [this tutorial](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/) on using the Python bindings to libclang, a while ago. Since the Python bindings are very lightweight, this tutorial can definitely be used to learn about the "vanilla" C libclang as well.

Comment: Yeah, I've already seen it (one of the better ones :). Aren't you planing to write one on syntax coloring/code completion ?

Comment: @user1307957: no, not at this point.